# Using Room Entity class as model while ionre field from database

Tags: kotlin, entity, android-room, data-class

I am using **Entity class** as model for **API response** it has `List<Address>` field I want it at serialization phase but i want to *ignore* it from stored in database as it will need **TypeConverter** and I don't want this.

```
@Entity(tableName = "USER")
data class User(
    @Ignore
    @SerializedName("address")
    val address: List<Address>?,
    @SerializedName("auth_token")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "authToken")
    val authToken: String?)
```

I have used `@Ignore` but got this error

```
error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
public final class User {
             ^
```

[image: Intelli J]

**Hint: I did not want to store this filed at db**

Answer (score 0):

i guess the problem is that you don't specify a default value for variable address. Try with this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "USER")
data class User(
  @SerializedName("auth_token")
  @ColumnInfo(name = "authToken")
  val authToken: String?
  @Ignore
  @SerializedName("address")
  val address: List<Address>? = null,
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you what is wrong:

> You can have [...] a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and
>   type)

Room has to know, how to construct your object from the database. When you use @Ignore on a parameter it is not listed as field. That's why parameters and fields don't match.

Therefor, you should not put **@Ignore**d fields in the constructor. 
Try doing the following:

```
@Entity(tableName = "USER")
data class User(
    @SerializedName("auth_token")
    @ColumnInfo(name = "authToken")
    val authToken: String?) {

    @Ignore
    @SerializedName("address")
    val address: List<Address>? = null
```

}